# Jerack curve - $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4w^{4}-20w^{3}+24w^{2}-20w+13}}{(w-2)^{2}\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}dw$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, curves, parametric

I wanted to calculate the length of the [Jerabek curve](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/jerabek/jerabek.shtml) which has equation:

$$(x^2+y^2)(x-1)^2=4(x^2+y^2-x)^2$$

**My work**

1. I used the coordinates to transform it into parametric form and arrived at:
   $$\left(\frac{2\cos(t)-1}{2-\cos(t)}\cos(t),\frac{2\cos(t)-1}{2-\cos(t)}\sin(t)\right)$$
2. I used the formula to calculate the length of parametric curves and arrived at this integral:
   $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt{4\cos(t)^4-20\cos(t)^3+24\cos(t)^2-20\cos(t)+13}}{\left(\cos(t)-2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}t$$
   $$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4w^{4}-20w^{3}+24w^{2}-20w+13}}{(w-2)^{2}\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}\mathrm{d}w$$

But I have no idea how to continue, can anyone help me?

Comment: The fourth degree polynomial implies an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I've never used them, would you be able to solve it with those?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't think this integral has a closed form in terms of known functions or constants (it's hard to work with that fourth degree polynomial)

Allow me to suggest a numerical solution, you can use [Chebyshev–Gauss quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature) since you have an integral between $-1$ and $1$ with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the denominator (which of all is the one with the easiest weight since it doesn't depend on $j$):

Let: $$f(x):=\frac{\sqrt{4x^{4}-20x^{3}+24x^{2}-20x+13}}{(x-2)^{2}}\quad \text{and}\quad x_j=\cos\left(\frac{2j-1}{n}\pi\right)$$

> Note that $f(x)$ is the same integrand as the problem but without $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to the denominator

---

Your integral can be calculated through this series:

$$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4w^{4}-20w^{3}+24w^{2}-20w+13}}{(w-2)^{2}\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}\mathrm{d}w\approx\frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{4x_{j}^{4}-20x_{j}^{3}+24x_{j}^{2}-20x_{j}+13}}{\left(x_{j}-2\right)^{2}}$$

Where $n$ it is a number that you can choose as large as you want (the higher it is, the more precise the integral will be). To have equality you must have:

$$\begin{matrix}\displaystyle2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4w^{4}-20w^{3}+24w^{2}-20w+13}}{(w-2)^{2}\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}\mathrm{d}w=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{4x_{j}^{4}-20x_{j}^{3}+24x_{j}^{2}-20x_{j}+13}}{\left(x_{j}-2\right)^{2}}\end{matrix}$$
To avoid having to calculate the cosine often, you can also write it by putting everything under the root and using partial fractions

Let $y_j:=2-\cos\left(\frac{2j-1}{2n}\pi\right)$:
$$\color{blue}{2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4w^{4}-20w^{3}+24w^{2}-20w+13}}{(w-2)^{2}\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}\mathrm{d}w\approx\frac{2\pi}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{4-\frac{12}{y_{j}}+\frac{36}{y_j^3}-\frac{27}{y_j^4}}}$$

> Even a term like this is simplified for you, you have one less

---

The integral is approssimativament equal to $6.562068241855779$ (calculated with [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NumberForm%5BNIntegrate%5B2%28%284%20w%5E4%20-%2020%20w%5E3%20%2B%2024%20w%5E2%20-%2020%20w%20%2B%2013%29%2F%28%281%20-%20w%5E2%29%20%28w%20-%202%29%5E4%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2C%7Bw%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D%2C20%5D))

- For $n=5$ you have: $\color{green}{6.5}\color{red}{763761665}$
- For $n=10$ you have: $\color{green}{6.562}\color{red}{19948899}$
- For $n=15$ you have: $\color{green}{6.5620}\color{red}{7041605}$
- For $n=20$ you have: $\color{green}{6.5620682}\color{red}{8605}$
- For $n=25$ you have: $\color{green}{6.56206824}\color{red}{286}$
- For $n=30$ you have: $\color{green}{6.5620682418}\color{red}{8}$